# Wasn't a user's post deleted unnecessarily?

Tags: support

Somebody asked: [Can a company pay its employees what they are worth and make money at the same time?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/23833/can-a-company-pay-its-employees-what-they-are-worth-and-make-money-at-the-same-t)

The question was voted down (not by me), and two participants asked the OP to edit the question to define "what [employees] are worth". Barely few seconds after I posted my answer, the post (and consequently my answer) was *deleted by Community*. As the reasoning in my answer reflects, it wasn't necessary to define "what they are worth".

There certainly are questions that are poorly formulated, but this is not one of them. I think the question is legitimate and shouldn't have been deleted. I clicked on "undelete answer", but to no avail. Can somebody undelete/restore the post (including my answer)?

Here's a copy/paste of my answer to the OP's question:

> Yes, it is theoretically possible to do so. By saying theoretically I
>   mean that, practical considerations aside (which largely depend on how
>   "employee's worth" is defined), the idea is not contrary to logic or
>   economics reasoning.
>
> Labor is not the only production factor. There are also capital and
>   inputs ("K&I") on which work is performed to produce a deliverable (be
>   it merchandise or services). Both capital and inputs are supplied or
>   funded by the company owner.
>
> Generally speaking, labor alone does not increase the company's wealth
>   (one exception is the typical IT intermediary who doesn't need to
>   invest any resources on employees' training or equipment because the
>   employee is qualified and the client already has the equipment set
>   up). And neither does K&I. It is the combination of labor and K&I what
>   generates revenues.
>
> The fact that labor is just one of the multiple requisite factors of
>   production does not imply that the entirety of profit derives from
>   employees' work. Furthermore, nothing prohibits the company to require
>   --via surcharges in pricing-- profit that derives exclusively from the use of K&I.
>
> To address the comments made to your question, a specific definition
>   of employees' worth is not necessary for determining whether it is
>   possible to pay employees their worth while also obtaining profit.
>   That definition would be needed only for determining how to achieve
>   that balance.

**Edited to add**

Never mind. It appears that that post has been restored. Thank you.

Comment: I think the question got deleted (automatically) by Community because the OP deleted their account.