# How can I find the anwer of an deleted question?

Tags: feature-request

Sometimes questions are deleted, like this [here](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1895/12910). When someone like me invests some work to answer such question, it is not nice that the answer isn't  readable in the personal activity. Or are answers somewhere else accessible?

Comment: I suggest posting this on meta.stackexchange.com, seems like a reasonable feature request. Us mods cant do anything about the actual framework of the site, only policy. I think its a good idea

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316094/how-can-i-find-my-own-answer-to-a-deleted-question/316097 Thanks for the hint.